# Can not run server after add sentry to nextjs project

Tags: next.js, sentry

I prefer the docs from https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs to add @sentry/nextjs to my project. Then i added their config to my next.config.js

```
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');
// module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig)
module.exports = {
}

const moduleExports = module.exports

const SentryWebpackPluginOptions = {
  // Additional config options for the Sentry Webpack plugin. Keep in mind that
  // the following options are set automatically, and overriding them is not
  // recommended:
  //   release, url, org, project, authToken, configFile, stripPrefix,
  //   urlPrefix, include, ignore

  silent: true, // Suppresses all logs
  // For all available options, see:
  // https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin#options.
};

// Make sure adding Sentry options is the last code to run before exporting, to
// ensure that your source maps include changes from all other Webpack plugins
module.exports = withSentryConfig(moduleExports, SentryWebpackPluginOptions);
```

Everythings seem to be fine before i run my server by yarn dev and got this error

```
Error: Could not find a valid build in the 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ws-or\fjob-frontend\.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
    at Server.readBuildId (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ws-or\fjob-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:137:355)
    at new Server (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ws-or\fjob-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:3:120)
    at Function.createServer [as default] (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ws-or\fjob-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:2:638)
    at Object.instrumentServer (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ws-or\fjob-frontend\node_modules\@sentry\nextjs\dist\utils\instrumentServer.js:42:67)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ws-or\fjob-frontend\node_modules\@sentry\nextjs\dist\index.server.js:56:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
(node:4084) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'default' of module exports inside circular dependency     
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4084) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'target' of module exports inside circular dependency      
(node:4084) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'amp' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:4084) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'experimental' of module exports inside circular dependency
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

After days of research i can not resolve this error. My nextjs config is empty and i do not think this is the problem of next. If i remove the sentry config, i can start my server like normal. Any idea?

Comment: What command do you run to start the server? Which version of the SDK are you using? Which version of next.js are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/3724
I guess your next.js version is too old.

Comment: @HazA yeah you are right, my nextjs version is too old. Thanks for update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is, upgrade next.js to >= 10.0.8 github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/3724

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Next.js version to latest works for me

run to upgrade to the latest version

```
npm install next@latest or yarn add next@latest
```

check [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading) for more info

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing .sentryclirc from my .gitignore file.
It was added automatically by Sentry there, and so it wasn't being added to the build.
(In case it helps someone)